# Apache-POI Generating tiny 8kb workbook taking minutes to complete

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache-POI to create a xlsx workbook. It was taking 15+mins to create a tiny 3 column 350 row workbook. I started trimming down the code (removing table formatting, etc>) but I realized that the generation of the workbook itself was taking minutes. This single line of code is taking minutes to complete:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Any tips on what I could be doing wrong, or what might be causing this huge delay in the background?

Edit: more context

```
System.out.println("Generating Excel file...");

System.out.println("  Creating workbook...");
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
System.out.println("  Creating sheet...");
XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("DS Datasources");
System.out.println("  Setting auto-filter...");
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:C1"));
```

In the console I see "Creating workbook..." and then I have to wait several minutes before I see "Creating sheet..." (which also takes over a minute). That means that single line of code is taking all that time, right?

Comment: This is just an object instantiation and shouldn't take much time. I suspect delay could be while writing/reading data. Can you paste the code snippet?

Comment: My guess is, that it's trying to do some kind of schema validation. Although this sounds strange, I would try to execute without internet connection. Next thing is to check the referenced xml jars - usually using some old xerces, xalan, xmlbeans, xmlapis, ... is also often the cause of strange effects.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will try to remove unnecessary jar, and get all the latest versions of the ones I do need.

Comment: @harshavmb I updated the question with more context.

Comment: What was your final resolution for this? I am experiencing a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185197/apache-poi-4-0-1-super-slow-getting-started-15-minutes-or-more-what-is-wron)

Comment: @pojo-guy I never ended up solving this issue.

Comment: It looks like this java JIT/classloader bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022063

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that under some circumstances, when the jar files in the project are compiled under different java levels (example 1 java 1.5 jar in a java 1.8 project) the JIT compiler will throw up its hands and run in pure interpreted mode. My resolution was to pull down the sources for the affected jars and build from source.