# Apache POI 4.0.1 super slow getting started ... 15 minutes or more. What is wrong?

Tags: java, ssl, spring-batch, classloader, jit

It takes 15 minutes or more for POI to initialize its first workbook in Java 8 on Windows 10, in a Tomcat 8 instance. Based on interrupting the process in the debugger and looking at the stack, it is spending the time in the classloader, driven by xbeans.

**Edit**
This has the feel of a classloader issue because when I implemented the workaround for the POI library (below), other classes started expressing the same issue.

**Edit**
The stack trace looks most similar to this bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022063

As you can see in jvisualvm, there is no classloader contention in the process thread taskExecutor-1.

[image: jvisualvm screenshot showing affected process]

I have a workaround, but it should not be necessary. The accepted answer will explain WHY this is happening.

**EDIT: Workaround**

During application initialization I added this line to the static class initializer for a configuration bean, to force the classloader to preload the classes and resources. It executes instantly there, and when the actual process is invoked it also executes instantly.

```
XSSFWorkbook preload = new XSSFWorkbook ();
```

The final workaround was to preload all of the jar files related to SSL, security, and POI. As near as I can tell, when loaded late in a spring batch context (may be a red herring), the classloader is attempting to validate the  bouncycastle jar files with algorithms encoded in the bouncycastle classes, and is running everything in the SSL stack in interpreted mode.

```
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("org.bouncycastle", this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<Class<? extends Object>> bouncyCastleClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);



        reflections = new Reflections("sun.security", this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<Class<? extends Object>> sunSecurityClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

        reflections = new Reflections("javax.ssl", this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<Class<? extends Object>> javaSslClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

        reflections = new Reflections("org.apache.poi", this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<Class<? extends Object>> poiClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

**POM excerpt:**

```
    <poi.version>4.0.1</poi.version>

        <!-- apache poi / poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code:

```
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        workbookname = "debuginfo-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".xlsx";
        logger.debug("Debug statistics dump file will be saved at [{}]", workbookname);
        debugStatsDump = new XSSFWorkbook(); // This line takes several minutes to run, apparently in the classloader???
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check time spent for POI 3.17 or 4.0.0?

Comment: Also have you tried starting Tomcat 8 with `unpack-wars=true`?

Comment: The update to 4.0.1 was because I was having he same issue with 3.17. I have not tried 4.0.0.  The host is configured with unpackWARs="true"

Comment: Try to start your Tomcat with this flag `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom`. You might be hitting this issue http://ruleoftech.com/2016/avoiding-jvm-delays-caused-by-random-number-generation, https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Java-Web-Applications-Slow-Startup-or-Failing

Comment: That looks interesting.  /dev/urandom is linux.  Is there an equivalent on Windows?

Comment: Frankly speaking I run Tomcat on Windows only during development but I've started java programs on Windows with exactly this flag `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom` and it worked.

Comment: It would still "work", it would just not do anything. It turns out my issue is a known bug in the JIT / classloader interaction that oracle/sun has known about since at least 2013, has been unable to reproduce reliably, and as of 2018 has marked as "won't fix" because they are going to stop signing those jars instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that under some circumstances when you mix jars from different versions of java (say 1.5 and 1.8), the JIT will throw up its hands and run in interpreted mode. There are several reports of the behavior listed on Oracle's website that say "we don't know why it's doing this, we won't fix it".

I downloaded sources for the libraries that were not compiled in 1.8 and built from source, and all is well.